# saving one object in 2 steps with activerecord

Tags: validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

in my user model i have attributes **nikname, email, password, and country**, about how to register users i want do this in 2 steps :

1. the first page shows form with 3 fields ( nikname, email, password ) , then user fills them and clicks signup button, and he will be redirected to a second page
2. the second page shows him a form with the last field ( country ) , then user fills it and clicks finish button to finish his registration

how i can do this ("saving 1 object in 2 step") , and for each step get errors of validation for each form

Comment: thanks for edit storaged

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this gem https://github.com/schneems/wicked could help you...
Cheers